# Resource temporarily unavailable error in Bash script using scp

Tags: bash, ubuntu-12.04, scp

To avoid installing `inotifywait` or `incron`, I've created a simple bash script to copy a file to a server whenever it changes using `scp` on Ubuntu 12.04:

```
FILE=filename.log
while true
do
    STDOUT=$(ls -l $FILE)
    [ "$STDOUT_OLD" != "$STDOUT" ] && STDOUT_OLD=$STDOUT && \
     scp -v $FILE hostname.com:/home/user/path/
    sleep 5
done
```

When I run it, it copies the file immediately, but subsequent changes to the file yields this error:

```
...
filename.log: Resource temporarily unavailable
Sink: scp: filename.log: Resource temporarily unavailable
...
```

I got the same error using a conventional `if` block:

```
if [ "$STDOUT_OLD" != "$STDOUT" ]
then
    STDOUT_OLD=$STDOUT
    scp -v $FILE hostname.com:/home/user/path/
fi
```

What's happening, and how can I fix it? Thanks!

Comment: Probably not the cause of your problem, but I'd suggest quoting "$FILE"

Comment: You're reinventing the `rsync` command.

Comment: This might help: [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/74329)